# Merge MP4 with M4A

Tags: software-recommendation, mp4

I have two files, one is **MP4** file with video only and another is **M4A** audio file. What is the best and simpliest method of merging these two tracks in a single MP4 container? Is it possible to do this without transcoding (loosing quality)? Thanks!

Open source and free software is my preference.

Comment: Do they actually line up correctly or do you also need to synchronize them?  If it is synced, this is effectively a duplicate of http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/10730/combine-video-and-audio-ts-segments-coming-from-hls-stream/.  Different source for the streams, but same solution should work.

Comment: I wouldn't say its a 100% duplicate. While the answer works, there are also other tools specifically for MP4.
The question might help people that search specifically for MP4 merging.

Comment: Scratch that, tsMuxer only allows MP4 as input not as output.

Answer (score 17):

[ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) looks promising. Might be worth a shot.

Specifically, the [command](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXfp4S1xZsw)

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.m4a -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.mp4
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

[MP4muxer](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/MP4Muxer) will do the job, it even takes raw h264 streams.

This process is usually called "muxing" and can be done with virtually any container format.
Of course audio and video has to have the exact same length to have synchronized audio and video.

Answer (score 2):

If your output container can handle the relevant codecs, then you can simply copy both audio and video streams using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.m4a -c copy output.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks, but how does it differs from the answer of the sgryzko?

Comment: It is simplified, yet provides the same resultant function.